# Firebase Cloud Functions fixed IP

Tags: firebase, ip, cloud, google-cloud-functions

Is there any way to get a fixed IP address for Firebase Cloud Functions? Or any workaround, such as free proxy? I don't need an "own" IP, just permanent one.

The problem is: Cloud Functions use external API and it requires to whitelist the Request IP Address.

Comment: Did you got any proxy or workarround?

Comment: @hkchakladar nope, I moved to own server

Comment: I'm using firebase as backend, but routing the external request via my another server as a proxy.